# Solving Relaxed Einstein Equation with xAct and xTensor packages

Tags: tensors, xact

First time question, involving tensor calculus.  I am entirely new to Mathematica and don't understand most of its conventions or jargon.  I'm trying to do tensor calculations in GR.

I've experimented with built-in features and various packages, and while they work for simple things, so far, the xAct/xTensor suit has been the closest to letting me do what I want to do.

The main thing I need from this package is that it lets me declare a symbol to have a type.  (For instance, to tell mathematica that the symbol $h$ represents a matrix without having to explicitly construct the matrix).

I'm trying to follow a set of chapters from the book Poisson & Will that develops the Post-Minkowski approach to GR, using the Relaxed Einstein Equations.  This is a perturbative approach, in powers of $G$.  For this, the convention is to define a slightly different perturbation
$$h^{ab} = \sqrt{-g}g^{ab} - \eta^{ab},$$
which should be contrasted with the usual perturbation $dg_{ab}$ defined by $$dg_{ab} = g_{ab} - \eta_{ab}.$$
The  two are related by $$dg^{ab} = (\sqrt{-g}-1)\eta^{ab} - h^{ab},$$
where $g=\det g^{ab},$ the determinant of the *full* metric.

The equation I eventually want to solve is
$$ \partial_c\partial^c h^{ab} = -\frac{16\pi G}{c^2} \tau^{ab},$$
where $h^{ab}$ is a series in powers of $G$ and $\tau^{ab}$ is a complicated function of $h^{ab}.$

If I work with the usual perturbation $dg_{ab}$, I can use the xPert package to do a lot of work for me, but then I can't use the actual relaxed einstein equations or the formalism, which require $h^{ab}.$  If I work with $h^{ab}$, then I don't get to use the xPert features.

If I can define one in terms of the other using a rule, then I can get the best of both. But I can't find any good way to do this.  Right now, I am using

```
DefMetricPerturbation[\[Eta], dg, G]
DefTensor[h[a, b], M4, Symmetric[{a, b}]]
AutomaticRules[dg, MakeRule[{dg[a, 
b], (Sqrt[-ExpandPerturbation[Perturbed[Det\[Eta][], 4]]] - 
   1)*\[Eta][a, b] - h[a, b]}, UseSymmetries -> True]]
```

But Mathematica doesn't like this.  It reports the cryptic errors:

```
Part: Part {2,3} of {a,b} does not exist
Part: Part {3,2} of {a,b} does not exist
```

then concludes

```
Rules {1,2} have been declared as DownValues for dg
```

none of which means anything to me.  The stack trace is equally opaque.

If I follow it up with

```
ExpandPerturbation[Perturbed[\[Eta][a, b], 2]]
```

then I get an answer in terms of $dg^{ab}$, and not $h^{ab}$ like I want.

I'm having all kinds of other conceptual problems, and sorting through the documentation is a challenge, and finding relevant examples is hard.  But I think if I could fix this, I'd be a step closer in the right direction.

Is this all hopeless?  Is there just no way to do this sort of thing?

Thanks in advance.

Update: With some experimentation, I **can** get the following to work:

```
DefMetricPerturbation[\[Eta], dg, G]
DefTensor[h[a, b], M4, Symmetric[{a, b}]]
detG = ToCanonical[
ExpandPerturbation[Perturbation[Sqrt[Det\[Eta][]], 4]]];
rule1 = MakeRule[{h[a, b], (detG - 1)*\[Eta][a, b] - dg[a, b]}];
```

which is to say, I can define $h^{ab}$ in terms of $dg^{ab}$, which is the *opposite* of what I want to do.  This doesn't help me at all, but maybe  to someone who knows will shine more light on why this doesn't work.